# cannot start browser for selenium through ssh

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium

I am trying to setup a linux box (no display connected) to run as a selenium server. If I connect a monitor and login on the box then I can run the selenium tests no problem. If I try to run the tests via ssh then the tests fail with

```
Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
at  org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:360)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:114)
```

I think it has something to do with the display's absence / presence. Any ideas?

PS the browser is firefox 5, the OS is Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: without connecting the monitor, are you manually able to open a firefox browser in that machine using ssh?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it to work by using [xvfb](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml). So first install xvfb:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

then run it

```
Xvfb :99 -ac
```

and then start the selenium server

```
DISPLAY=:99 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.4.0.jar
```

Comment: Similar thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335717/selenium-and-headless-environment

Comment: Can the same be done with python selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929685/running-test-ng-selenium-tests-through-ssh/19236773#19236773).

You get this error because there is no monitor to open firefox on, it is getting confused.

Install Xvfb, which pretends to be a monitor, but doesn't show up anywhere. 

`sudo apt-get install xvfb`

If you want less errors add these fonts, but those warning aren't important.

`sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic`

Then start it running and set your display to something the system won't use. Here is what I do, remeber the `&` makes the terminal run something in the background.

`Xvfb :99 -ac &`

`export DISPLAY=:99`

`firefox &`

Also I was having problems with a ruby on rails server disconnecting when I quit the ssh terminal. To fix that problem use Screen. Screen runs another terminal without being affected by the ssh. 

`sudo apt-get install screen`

Then just start screen before you you do the stuff above. 

`screen`

To get out of the current screen window just click "Ctrl + A" and to get back in type screen -r.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way to test using imagemagick screen shoot

Install mozilla firefox headless(no GUI)

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64 xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi firefox ImageMagick.x86_64
```

Starts firefox on virtual gui

```
DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://google.com &
```

– test and check

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 1 1024x768x24 &
ps -ef |grep firefox
```

Uses imagemagic to get a printscreen, to make sure its working.
**DISPLAY=:1 import -window root google.com.png**

(Optional) Set proxy in firefox profile

```
vi /root/.mozilla/firefox/ns11i9xo.default/prefs.js
user_pref(“network.proxy.http”, “proxyserver”);
user_pref(“network.proxy.http_port”, 8080);
user_pref(“network.proxy.no_proxies_on”, “localhost, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.0/16, 10.5.0.0/16″);
```

http://felipeferreira.net/?p=1220